# Java string replace

Tags: java, optimization, strings

I am new to Java and I am trying to learn about optimizing code to make it production ready. I have the following code below. I would like to know how I could optimize it. I thought by using a small snippet of could, it would be a good way to learn.

Some points:

1. The function would be run many times to it needs to be fast.
2. The input is unconstrained since it might come from a user or from a file. Is there a way to deal with this so not exceptions are thrown? I was thinking of using a regular expression.
3. Is there anything else I need to do to make it production ready? e.g. unit tests. If so, what would be the best way to do this?
4. I am assuming that the string to be searched is not very long.
5. When I say optimization, I mean doing things like replacing the `+` operator with something faster is it can effect memory and performance, etc.

```
public String strReplave(String originalStr, String oldStr, String newStr) {
    int start = 0;
    while ((start = originalStr.indexOf(oldStr, start)) > 0) {
        originalStr= originalStr.substring(0,start) + newStr+ originalStr.substring(start + oldStr.length());
    start += newStr.length();
}
return originalStr;
}
```

Thanks for your help and if you need me to clarify anything please let me know.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something?  Why don't you use `String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement);`?  `String`s implement `CharSequence`, so you could use that like `String ns = "Hello world".replace("world", "people");`

Answer (score 5):

String.replace(..) will work as Corbin said.

Be careful when you mix String objects with the '+' operator in Java, especially within a loop.

```
String s = a + b;
```

will be (generally) interpreted as

```
String s = new StringBuffer(a).append(b).toString();
```

While not bad on it's own, when performed in a loop, a new StringBuffer (or the newer StringBuilder) object will be created on every loop iteration, which is usually sub-optimal.

When you want to build a String up from pieces, consider storing the result in a StringBuilder object (created outside of the loop) as you go.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [`StringUtils.replace`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) instead. It's open source, so you can check [its source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java?view=markup#l3764) and its [unit tests](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtilsTest.java?view=markup#l968) too. [`StringUtils.replaceEach`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceEach%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) also could be useful.

> By using a standard library,
>   you take advantage of the knowledge of the experts who wrote it and the
>   experience of those who used it before you.

It's from *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries* where the author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.

See also: [Not Invented Here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?NotInventedHere)

Answer (score 3):

Like Corbin said you have to use replace(..), or replaceAll(..) [native Java functions],
 and test the parameters :

```
public String strReplave(final String originalStr, final String oldStr, String newStr) {
    // add 'final' if parameters are not changed
    if(null == originalStr || originalStr.isEmpty()) {
          return ""; // verify if it is the project solution prerequity
    }
    if(null == oldStr || oldStr.isEmpty()){
        // Send also a  message to Console or API logger 
        return originalStr ;
    }
    if (null == newStr) {
        newStr = ""; // verify if it is the project solution prerequity
    }
    return originalStr.replaceAll(oldStr, newStr);
}
```

Comment: It's probably a typo: `originalStr(replaceAll(oldStr, newStr))`

Comment: @palacsint Exact! Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I assume this would not take care of especial characters in the string. That they would still through an exception?

Comment: A String is `null` or not; so inside characters can be evaluate and replaced with regex like : 
`Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex, flags);
String result = patt.matcher(input).replaceAll(replacement);`